# ubuntu active directory domain controller with AWS LAMP server

Tags: server, lamp, active-directory, aws

I have a AWS LAMP server.

We are bunch of people to develops the open source stuff. As now many people have joined us, we are thinking to have a active directory domain controller.

I have gone through this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rf7Hk8qWt1Q video where its mentioned that how we can do it! This may work well on local.

But we all work from different location. We have AWS LAMP server. Is it possible to install mentioned things on same server and will it work as we need?